# RetroFit response parameter after a Post

Tags: java, retrofit

In this code below I am using RetroFit2 to post an object to an endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/insert:`

```
Call<DeviceModel> deviceModelCall = api.createDevice(device);
deviceModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<DeviceModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DeviceModel> call, Response<DeviceModel>
                                response) {
        //How do I get access to the {"success" : true} object sent as a response form the endpoint after I posted.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<DeviceModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Failure", "ON FAILURE" + "Failure");
    }
});
```

Now in my Node API if the save of the object was successful I returning a JSON object: `{"success" : true}`.

But in the above `onResponse` method the `response` variable in the parameters is of type `Response<DeviceModel>`. How do I extract that the `{"success" : true}` object which I send back from the node API below in the above method in `onResponse()`? Is there any way to do that?

```
router.post('/insert', function(req, res) {
    //Create Object
    var obj = new Device({
    });

    obj.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("SAVE NOT SUCCESSFUL"); 
        }else {
            console.log("SAVE SUCCESS");
            res.json({
                "success" : true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you use a `Call<DeviceModel>` if the response is not a `DeviceModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should head over to the OkHTTP documentation, which is what Retrofit uses under the hood.

`response.body()` should give you a `DeviceModel`, **but** that seems like a strange name for a class that would only have a `boolean success` field, so I think your Retrofit API Design needs some work...

Note: The response body can **be consumed only once** and it **must be closed**.

For example, a try-with-resources

```
   Call<DeviceModel> call = client.newCall(request);
   call.enqueue(new Callback<DeviceModel>() {
     public void onResponse(Call<DeviceModel> call, Response<DeviceModel> response) throws IOException {
       try (DeviceModel model = response.body()) {
         // TODO: use model
       }
     }

     public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
       ... // Handle the failure.
     }
   });
```

Source - [`ResponseBody`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html)

You can use `response.body().string()` to get the raw JSON string if you really wanted it.

Comment: Oh my `DeviceModel` has over 6 fields. But I just want to send back a response with just the JSON object `{"success" : true}`. And I want to check the `success` key in the `onResponse` callback and test whether if it is true or not and then do something in the app if the device was saved successfully. Or will the response.body will always be a DeviceModel object?

Comment: If you use a `Call<DeviceModel>`, then you'll get a `Response` that is a `DeviceModel`. You can easily re-write your createDevice API Method to return something else

Comment: Realistically, though, shouldn't you return the entire object that was created by the database? Can't you safely assume that a 200 response code from the API is a "success"?

Comment: Yes I think I will just go about doing that with the 200 response code. I will check the response code in `onResponse()` and do whatever is needed. Thank you for the help.